# How to assign keyboard keys as shortcut for menu items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have menu items like purchase order, delivery menu etc. I want to assign `f3` as shortcut for delivery memo and also for other menu items also. So How do I do that?? Following is my code, it may be wrong . Because I dont know the logic behind this kind of functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode;
        if (keycode == 65) {
            alert("asda");
            $("#change").trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You seem like you pretty much have it, this should work

Comment: It's not working..even alert is not coming when I press 'a'

Comment: BTW: In jQuery you have to use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`

Comment: hindmost, this is totally incorrect you can use either and its recommended to use both

Comment: kedar what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (arguments[0].key == 65) {
        alert("F3 pressed");
        document.location.href = 'new address'; // updated from comments
    }
});
```

Comment: Now Alert is coming but how do I redirect to that page means calling ajax or something else?? I am doing this in codeigniter..

Comment: I dont know codeigniter... but... if you want to redirect to a new page `window.open(url)` will work... if you want to reload a part of the actual view you must program javascript actions to be performed inside the if ;)

Comment: window.open(url) will open a new window - document.location.href = 'new address' will act like a link clicked and will also save history

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code...And I have put this code in my header file so this code will work on any page of my site.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var keycode = e.keyCode;
        if (keycode == 114) {

            document.location.href='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/purchase";?>';
        }
    });
});
```